# Pandas groupby year and plot graph

Tags: python, pandas

This is related to the Kaggle Dataset for " H-1B Visa Petitions 2011-2016":

```
 [In]: df.groupby(['EMPLOYER_NAME','YEAR']).size().sort_values(ascending=False).head(10)

[Out]:

    EMPLOYER_NAME                      YEAR
    INFOSYS LIMITED                    2015    33245
                                       2013    32223
                                       2016    25352
                                       2014    23759
    CAPGEMINI AMERICA INC              2016    16725
    TATA CONSULTANCY SERVICES LIMITED  2015    16553
    INFOSYS LIMITED                    2012    15818
    TATA CONSULTANCY SERVICES LIMITED  2014    14098
                                       2016    13134
    WIPRO LIMITED                      2015    12201
```

I wanted to group index "Infosys Limited" by year together as shown below, because currently in the above output it is showing Infosys Limited for 2012 separately and also need to plot the graph to know the trends for these companies in last 5 years, I'm using matplotlib & seaborn for graphs, Not sure if we can plot such graphs using these tools. Any help much appreciated.

```
Infosys Limited 2012    15818
                2013    32223
                2014    23759
                2015    33245
                2016    25352

Graph:
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's try this bit of code:

```
 df1 = df.groupby(['EMPLOYER_NAME','YEAR']).size().unstack()
 df1.columns = df.columns.droplevel()
 df1.plot(kind='barh')
```

[image]

Comment: Throws error: AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'droplevel'

Comment: Just remove that line.  I had a different data arrangement than you.

Comment: You have hit the nail at the right place. Take a bow. it works like charm after some minor modifications  by adding sorting to get the top n rows..thanks a ton

Comment: Just curious, for wipro i can see only one bar i.e. for 2015, looks like for rest of the year it doesn't came up in the sorting, is there a way we can just get all the years (2012-2016) for top ten employers.

Comment: Wipro has one record because of the .head(10)  if you did the entire dataframe you would get all companiess.  However, if you want to see the top ten employers, first you limit your dataframe to those top ten employers and then do the groupby, and etc...

Answer (score 2):

This is really a series of questions, so in the future try to whittle it down to one specific item.

1. "I wanted to group index "Infosys Limited" by year together as shown below, because currently in the above output it is showing Infosys Limited for 2012 separately"

It is separate because you sorted the values. Take off `sort_values` and look at your output again, it should be grouped the way you want.

2. "and also need to plot the graph to know the trends for these companies in last 5 years"

The graph you show is produced most likely in R using [ggplot2](http://ggplot2.org/). There is a version of ggplot that has been ported to python, but it isn't quite as wonderful as the R version. If you want graphs that look exactly like this you could start there. As far as matplotlib is concerned, you can steal the ggplot styling by calling `pyplot.style.use('ggplot')` at the beginning of your scripts. But beware as some of the more complex ggplot charts can be hard to exactly replicate in matplotlib.

Comment: My bad, will try to structre my Q in future. back to my query, if i remove sorting then there are 100 million rows and it's difficult to get the top 10 companies so that's the reason i put the sorting on the result. is there a work around? 2) I'm a python guy so it's really tough to use R for my work, either i can try on tableau but it's public version doesn't support this heavy data, it breaks down.

Comment: Even after grouping with employer and year you have 100M rows? You could just group by company to get the total for all years and use the top ten companies from that as a filter for your employer/year grouping.